# How to sort products into categories Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have toons of products in a magento store thats need to be 
sorted into new categories based on diffrent attributes any 
one knows how to do this with a script.

example:

if the product attribute "COLOR" has a value of Blue the product should be in cat 10
and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you iterate over your products you can use the setCategoryIds method (this code is meant to be used for a dropdown attribute as it uses the getAttributeTextMethod):

```
$product->load($productId);
if( strcmp($product->getAttributeText('COLOR') , 'Blue') == 0 ){
    $product->setCategoryIds(array('cat1Id' ,'cat2Id'));
}
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks baoutch for the input i'll will try this today